# MSAL redirectLogin and B2C: tokenReceivedCallback not always called

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I setup MSAL clientside authentication, and it works in around 80% of the cases I would say, in the rest of them, it seems the tokenReceivedCallback is not called. Whenever this happens, login stops working until browser is closed...

Im having some trouble finding examples of how to use MSAL with the redirectLogin, it seems all examples just use the "loginPopup"(which IMHO is not very user friendly, I tried it and my users complained about login popup being lost behind other windows all the time).

Does anybody have an example of how MSAL should be setup with B2C and redirectLogin? Or a suggestion of how I should troubleshoot this issue?
Or at least an overview of how this flow is supposed to work?(Im having trouble udnerstanding how the callback is triggered after a redirect...)

This comment in this issue seemed very promising, but it seems the sample has been removed, or is this methid being deprecated?
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/issues/10#issuecomment-327204996

Comment: Hi Tompi, what kind of front end tech/framework are you working with?

Comment: @AndyM Im using vue and webpack, tried moving the newing of the msal application object before initializing vue, but still missing callbacks sometimes... wondering what is supposed to trigger the tokenreceivedcallback...

Comment: I know this isn't much help but I eventually gave up trying to get Vue to work because of similar issues. I've moved over to angular which has an MS provided NPM package which wraps MSAL with good docs. Sorry I can't be of any help.